# Nifi: How to update or add items to existing parameter context using CLI or toolkit?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-toolkit

I am using Nifi parameter context to avoid hardcoding multiple variables.

I used toolkit to create parameter context and used parameters inside my flow.

Now I want to update some values of this existing parameter context to 1.update some values or 2. add new parameters.

I could not find a way using toolkit in the documentation.

I saw an answer here https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Update-parameter-contexts-dynamically-using-REST-API/m-p/347697 But i am looking for any solution based on toolkit or other easier approach, so that it can be easily handled while deployments to next environments or while updating it in production environments.

Please help me with your approach or suggestions.